# Integrating a new language with dialog flow agent

Tags: api, nlp, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, agent

I see multiple supported language in the dialog flow but I want to ask if I can integrate a new language as Arabic, 
Is there the ability to add a new language and how ?
If I want to implement the new package for the Arabic NLP by myself  How I can start learning, it will be based on what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a language that is not supported by Dialogflow, there is no way to add support for that language. You would either have to wait for support or use a different NLP tool.

Comment: okay,do you have an idea of how I can implement just a basic example of NLP that support Arabic for example.it's based on what ?

Comment: You'd probably want to look at a service like [Cloud AutoML](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/) or learn how to use something like Tensorflow to do it manually